# Rails - Accessing model class methods from within ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I have a simple standalone model that doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord or anything else, called `SmsSender`. As the name suggests, it delivers text messages to an SMS gateway.

I also have an ActiveRecord model called `SmsMessage` which has an instance method called `deliver`:

```
def deliver
  SmsSender.deliver_message(self)
  self.update_attributes :status => "Sent"
end
```

The above is returning `uninitialized constant SmsSender`. I'm sure this is dead simple, but how can I access the SmsSender class from within my model?

Comment: Where is `SmsSender` being defined? Where is the actual file in your tree? If it's in a special directory, did you add that directory to the load path?

Comment: It's in the bog standard models path. Elsewhere in the application I access SmsSender from a controller and it works fine. This piece of functionality is developed to be used with `delayed_job` so I don't know if that has any impact on what is or isn't loaded?

Comment: Ah, silly me! I just spotted my errors. I'd actually called the class `SMSSender` (note capitalization) and the filename `sms_sender.rb`. I believe Rails is sensitive to that kind of thing. Just renamed the class to `SmsSender` as per my post and the class is getting loaded correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

Mabe ruby looks for `SmsSender` inside the current class.
Try to use the (global) [scope resolution operator](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176683) `::` like this:

```
def deliver
  ::SmsSender.deliver_message(self)
  self.update_attributes :status => "Sent"
end
```

Also make sure the file for `SmsSender` is included (via one of: require, load etc)